# Initiate 'exit' on motion component before useState switches to Route component

Tags: reactjs, use-state, framer-motion

I have a `<motion.div>` element which animates through some Framer Motion variants before rendering the `<Home/>` route component.

The 'hidden' and 'visible' animation targets for `<motion.div>` work as expected, but I'm unsure how to get the 'exit' animation to fire before/on setTimeout ends and the `<Home/>` component renders.

```
  const animation = { 

    hidden: {
      opacity:0,
      x: 0,
    },
    visible: {
      opacity:1,
      x: 10,
    },
    exit: {
      opacity:0,
      x: 0,
    }
  }

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false)
    }, 2000)
  }, [])

  return (

    <AnimatePresence initial="false" exitBeforeEnter>
      <div className="flex">
        <div>

        {
          loading 
        ? 
          <motion.div 
            style={{
              width:100,
              height:100,
              backgroundColor: "orange"
            }}
            variants = {animation}
            initial = 'hidden'
            animate = 'visible'
            exit = 'exit'>

          </motion.div>
        :

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/about">
              <About/>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        }

        </div>
      </div>
    </AnimatePresence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
     <div className="flex">
      <div>
        <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
          {loading ? (
            <motion.div
              style={{
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                backgroundColor: "orange",
              }}
              variants={animation}
              initial="hidden"
              animate="visible"
              exit="exit"
              key="loader"
            ></motion.div>
          ) : (
            <Switch key="switch">
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/about">
                <About />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          )}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Note:

1. I move the animate presence to immediate surround your elements in question
2. I added explicit keys to the children of inside AnimatePresense, which is required even if they are a fragment

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @joshua-wootonn this worked brilliantly, thank you!